# Silverlight Navigation project template and the WrapPanel

Tags: silverlight, navigation, wrappanel

I'm new to Silverlight and I'm trying to get the [WrapPanel](http://silverlight.net/content/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html) sample working with the Navigation project template. My issue is that the WrapPanel doesn't wrap.

Here's what I've tried:
Create a new Navigation based project.
Copy the code from the Toolkit Samples for the "Select a Color" demo.

When I create a "regular" Silverlight application the WrapPanel does wrap as expected.

Any ideas on what I might be missing with the Navigation based project?

Answer (score 1):

Is your WrapPanel grouped into a StackPanel? In case your WrapPanel is located inside a StackPanel, it will never wrap.